# как сделать плавный slider на JS

Tags: javascript, css

сделал слайдер, всё работает, только не пойму как сделать плавный переход по картинкам:

```js
let image=document.querySelector('img')
for(let i=1;i<=3;i++){
     setInterval(function(){
        i++
    if(i>3){
        i=1
    }
      image.src='img/'+i+'.jpg'
     },2000)
}
```

```html
<img src="img/1.jpg" alt="" width="400" height="200">
```

Comment: так вы просто src подменяете ...а плавная анимация на css делается с ease

Comment: @MaximLensky, т.е. нужно на ```img``` нужно сделать ```setAttribute```?

Comment: да нее, всю анимацию надо сделать на css __напишите в codepen в поиске  `image slider` там увидите как реализованная анимация переключения

Comment: щас вам тут 100500 вариантов слайдеров накидают а вы так и не поймёте что там отвечает за анимацию переключения ..